# Bewildered about standardUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c

Greetings StackOverflow community,

I put a breakpoint on the first line in main(argc, argv) function to see what [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] holds and I was surprised to see that it already had many parameters and values from the application's previous execution.

At what stage are user defaults loaded into memory? Where are they saved once the application terminates?

Thank you!

Sleiman

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982740/where-is-a-mac-applications-nsuserdefaults-data-stored

Comment: Thanks turbo! Does this mean that these user defaults are global to the device and not necessarily specific to the application?

Comment: because of sandboxing you can't access another apps data.