# Where is data for NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults stored on MacOS?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

Where is the data for NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults stored on MacOS? I would like to edit stored values as is possible in the Windows Registry. I am using XCode 12.3 on Catalina. Finder search does not show any non-source code file on the machine which contains the persisted values. No .plist files shown via Finder appear to store the persisted values.

Comment: Duplicate of [Where is a Mac Application's NSUserDefaults Data Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982740/where-is-a-mac-applications-nsuserdefaults-data-stored)

Comment: None of the locations described in the duplicate question contain a .plist file containing the standardDefaults data. However, the data can be viewed by typing `po [[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]persistentDomainForName:BundleIdentifier]`at the debug console. BundleIdentifier is shown in the General tab of the Project.xcodeproj file.

Comment: How do you write to the user defaults?

Comment: Writing to standardDefaults is done via the Bindings inspector for bound controls and via  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:<Value> forKey:<key string> for other values

Comment: Does `~/Library/Containers/com.example.myapp/Data/Library/Preferences/com.example.myapp.plist` exist? When do you check? Can you read standardDefaults when you start the app?

Comment: There is no directory MacHDD/Library/Containers

Comment: See [what does “~/.” mean in terms of OS X folders/directories?](https://superuser.com/questions/158721/what-does-mean-in-terms-of-os-x-folders-directories)

Comment: Have found the hidden folder /Users/apple/Library/containers (user name is Apple User) but there is no subfolder corresponding to the bundle identifier of the XCode project (ch.seriot.CocoaSlideShow)

Comment: Found the file Users/apple/Library/Preferences/ch.seriot.CocoaSlideShow.plist which presumably contains the standardDefault preferences. Is there any way to show this file in Finder?

Comment: Holding down cmd, shift and period shows hidden folders in Finder and inspection shows that the file above does contain the stadardDefaults preferences. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting the file Users/apple/Library/Preferences/ch.seriot.CocoaSlideShow does not seem to affect the default values retrieved  and neither does setting values from Xcode when the .plist file is opened in Xcode so perhaps this file does not contain the standardUserDefaults values. The values shown by `po [[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]persistentDomainForName:BundleIdentifier]` are not identical to those shown in XCode.