# Where to find userdefaults.plist file when values written by a root process?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I have a CLI executable(running in root context).It's sole purpose is to writeUserDefaults and read UserDefaults, and its working fine as it supposed to but I am unable to find the plist file created/modified by this process. I tried running same process in user context and was  able to find the plist file created by it  in ~/Library/Preference/ServiceCheckOne.plist

`UserDefaults.init(suiteName: 'ServiceCheckOne')?.set(100, forKey: 'check1')` 
`let value = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: suiteName)?.integer(forKey: key)!` 
After using this functions i am getting value = 100

I searched for plist from all the locations mentioned in these answer and the build

[Where is a Mac Application's NSUserDefaults Data Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982740/where-is-a-mac-applications-nsuserdefaults-data-stored)

locate command didn't help either. 
I checked recently modified files still not able to find file.
In short 
Need help locating the ServiceCheckOne.plist file when u userDefaults.set is used by root process.\

Or am I getting value back because of caching of defaults and file actually didn't exist?
Thank you
Xcode 12.3
MacOs 10.15
Tried defaults read | grep ServiceCheckOne got no hits here too

Comment: Is your App sandboxed?

Comment: Have you looked in /var/root/Library/Preferences/ServiceCheckOne.plist? Depending on exactly what you mean by "root context", that's where I'd expect to find it.

Comment: No App is not sand boxed @LeoDabus

Comment: ,I checked in /root/Library/Preferences.When i said root context I mean ,I am using this Command line executable  as a root Launch Agent. @GordonDavisson

Comment: @krishnavamsi any luck in finding user defaults location for root processes?

Comment: @DesertRose I am able to find them sudo defaults read <suitename>, but still, I couldn't find the suitename.plist file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

- `/private/var/root/Library/Preferences`
- `/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost`