# In OSX where is user preferences are for the Bundle?

Tags: macos, cocoa

In [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/1516992-autosavesconfiguration?language=objc) (`NSToolbar autosavesConfiguration`) it is mentioned that the toolbar configuration is saved into the user defaults.

Where are they located and how do I edit them?

I'm on OSX 10.13 using Xcode 9.

My application is not meant for iPhone/iPad, it's a regular Desktop one.

Comment: [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc)

Comment: @HangarRash, thx for the reply. Maybe I didn't express myself properly - what I am looking for is the place on the disk where the default toolbar configuration is stored so I can remove it and test my code changes.

Comment: They are stored in some opaque system database not intended to be directly manipulated. You can use the `defaults` command line tool to modify or completely remove your app's settings. See `defaults -h`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is a Mac Application's NSUserDefaults Data Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982740/where-is-a-mac-applications-nsuserdefaults-data-stored)

Comment: @GerdK, then how do you test the application if you can't directly manipulate the defaults? There has to be a way to edit and remove them in order to see what is happening...

Comment: @Willeke, I will check that tonight. Thx.

Comment: Note that the answer @Willeke links to is no longer valid. And you can manipulate the defaults directly with the `defaults` command line tool. As I have mentioned, `defaults -h` will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @GerdK, thx. Why does his/her answer invalid? I didn't check it yet and so just curious...

Comment: The linked answer was valid at the time it was written. Apple has since changed the way user defaults are managed, going from a per-app file-based representation (as that answer showed) to a system-wide database. That happened a few years ago.

Comment: @GerdK, understood. I am working with OSX 10.13, so it may still be applicable. I'll check both. Thx.

Comment: The `defaults` command line tool will work for either case.